# Disable adsense ads ABOVE mobile site (blogger)

Tags: javascript, layout, blogger, adsense

I have a blog with Adsense enabled. I recently noticed that ads were not displaying, so I re-saved my settings in blogger and they showed back up. Unfortunately, they are now taking over the entire top half of my mobile site! I need to disable ads ABOVE my website, and if that’s not possible, disable them on mobile entirely. Can anyone help me please?

Visit www.dfwcraftshows.com on a mobile to see what I mean, or here is a screen cap:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4017zdffb0ttgl/adexample.png?dl=0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem came because you activate ads in Blogger dashboard. If you won't Blogger place Ads automatically, you can disable that setting. And place manually Ad from Template Editor.

You can disable blogger adsense ad setting in Blogger dashboard.

Go to your Blogger dashboard

Click tab Earning

Choose No in 'display ads in my blog'

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: I was under the impression that Adsense wants you to use this integration with blogger to avoid violating TOS in terms of number of ads displaying etc. it is weird the settings say they will only show underneath, but then they do not...